# Plotly error with continuous color variable and x or y as factor

Tags: r, plotly

I'm trying to understand why this produces an error:

```
data(mpg)
mpg$model <- as.factor(mpg$model)
mpg %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~class, y = ~model, color = ~displ) %>%
  add_markers()
```

I get: "Error in Summary.factor(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,  :  ‘range’ not meaningful for factors"

The issue seems to arise if color is continuous and either x or y is a factor variable.  Converting the factor with as.character() removes the error (I did the opposite here just to show the error), but then I lose the ordering of the factor levels.  Is this a bug or is there some reason why I shouldn't be able to do this?

Comment: Try color = ~factor(displ)

Comment: That gets around the error, but then I lose the continuous color range I'd like to keep.